# Removing plotly click event data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am designing a Shiny app which contains a `plotly` scatter plot. I would like for the user to be able to click on the graph to record an event using the `event_data` function, but then be able to clear that event on the click of an `actionButton`. Some example code can be seen below:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("clearEvent", label = "clear event"),
  verbatimTextOutput("plotVal"),
  plotlyOutput('plot1')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
    plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, color = ~carat,
            size = ~carat, text = ~paste("Clarity: ", clarity))
  })

  output$plotVal <- renderPrint({
    e <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(e)) {
      NULL
    } else {
      e
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input[["clearEvent"]], {
    e <- NULL
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This doesn't clear the event like I would expect, however. Looking into the code for `event_data` shows that this is probably because it is stored within the `session` object itself. Any ideas how I can overwrite it?

The only similar thing I have come across is [Clear plotly click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858767/clear-plotly-click-event) but it's very hacky and doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `e` is just defined in the `renderPrint` and in the `observeEvent`  and not globally so even if `e` is changed in the `observeEvent`, it does not trigger anything in the `renderPrint`.

You can use `reactiveValues` for this:

```
data <- reactiveValues(e=NULL)

  observe({
    data$e <- event_data("plotly_click")
  })

  output$plotVal <- renderPrint({
    e <- data$e
    if (is.null(e)) {
      NULL
    } else {
      e
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input[["clearEvent"]], {
    data$e <- NULL
  })
```

`data$e` is changed whenever the user click the plot or the button, and since there is a dependency on `data$e` in the `renderPrint`, that gets updated whenever `data$e` is changed.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer partially solves the problem, however, the user cannot click on the same plotly marker again, at least no update is triggered. That problem can be tackled by manually resetting the source of `event_data("plotly_click")` with`shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    # code to reset plotlys event_data("plotly_click", source="A") to NULL -> executed upon action button click
    # note that "A" needs to be replaced with plotly source string if used
    extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('.clientValue-plotly_click-A', 'null'); }"),
    actionButton("reset", "Reset plotly click value"),
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    verbatimTextOutput("clickevent")
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x=~cyl, y=~mpg)
  })

  output$clickevent <- renderPrint({
    event_data("plotly_click")
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    js$resetClick()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: is there a way to adjust this so that it works for plotly_selected events?

Comment: Change to `extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('plotly_click-A', 'null'); }")` with new version of plotly to make it work,  and `'plotly_selected-A'` to make it work for selections

Comment: So to sum up you should remove `.clientValue-` from `extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('.clientValue-plotly_click-A', 'null'); }")`

Comment: if you are trying to fix the clicking on the same plotly marker again. Here's the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755775/6090977). They fixed it on the plotly side.