# clicking same plotly marker twice does not trigger events twice

Tags: r, modal-dialog, shiny, plotly, shinyjs

I am using Plotly's `event_data("plotly_click")` to do stuff (opening a modal) after the user clicked on a marker in a scatter plot. Afterwards (e.g. closing the modal), `event_data("plotly_click")` does of course not change and clicking on the same marker therefore does not trigger the same action again.

Minimal example:

```
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(  
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    mtcars %>% plot_ly(x=~disp, y=~cyl)
  }) 

  # Do stuff after clicking on a marker in the plot
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click"), {
    print("do some stuff now") # this is not executed after second click on same marker
  })  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried workarounds with shinyjs's `onclick`, to no avail (it works well in empty areas of the plot but not when clicking on markers):

```
shinyjs::onclick(id="plot", print("clicked"))
```

I have also tried using a reactive Value that stores the last click and is reset immediately afterwards (e.g. by `event_data("plotly_hover")`), but all tries fail because `event_data("plotly_click")` remains in its old value.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this is a know issue https://community.plot.ly/t/reseting-click-events/2718

Comment: thanks, but that is just a link to a lone question in their forum, no trace of tracked issue or similar :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue has finally been fixed on Plotly side: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1043

`event_data("plotly_click", priority = "event")` updates on every click, not only on shiny input change (as before). Working from Plotly 4.9.0 on.

Minimal example using **Plotly 4.9.0**:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot", height = 200),
    verbatimTextOutput("time_last_click")
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars[1,], x=~cyl, y=~mpg, size = 1)
  })


  output$time_last_click <- renderPrint({
    tmp <- event_data("plotly_click", priority = "event")
    Sys.time()
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**[Edit: The issue has been fixed in Plotly 4.9.0. See answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755775/6498638). This answer works up to Plotly 4.8.0. From plotly 4.9.0., delete the string `.clientValue-` from the source code or use [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755775/6498638).]**

I finally solved this issue. I know this is bothering some people, so I'll post my solution here:

Basically I use `shinyjs` package to reset the data about the last click (the source where `event_data("plotly_click")` gets its information from) on a certain event (a button in my case).

The definition of the function is (note that "A" needs to be replaced with plotly-source string if used):

```
extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('.clientValue-plotly_click-A', 'null'); }")
```

Then this is called upon button click by `js$resetClick()`.

Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    # code to reset plotlys event_data("plotly_click", source="A") to NULL -> executed upon action button click
    # note that "A" needs to be replaced with plotly source string if used
    extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('.clientValue-plotly_click-A', 'null'); }"),
    actionButton("reset", "Reset plotly click value"),
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    verbatimTextOutput("clickevent")
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x=~cyl, y=~mpg)
  })

  output$clickevent <- renderPrint({
    event_data("plotly_click")
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    js$resetClick()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @shosaco I copied this exact example and the click is not being reset. I'm on R 3.6.0 and my `sessionInfo()` looks like the following: `[1] shinyjs_1.0   plotly_4.9.0  ggplot2_3.1.1 shiny_1.3.2 `. Is there an issue with the new plotly library? I've also used the `priority = "event"` change as shown below but the javascript is still not being reset.

Comment: Dear @Agrosel, thanks for the note! In 4.9.0, they changed the input name. For 4.8.0, the above example is working, for Plotly 4.9.0, you must use the line `extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('plotly_click-A', 'null'); }"),`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and came up with a solution where I specified the **source** argument of the plotly object to be a **reactive value** as follows:

In `plot_ly(data,x,y,...,source = x)` and `event_data(...,source = x)` let `x` be an element of a `reactiveValues` object.  When your event triggers, change the value of x (increment or hash), which instantiates a new `event_data()` object.

Worked like a charm.

Comment: Consider updating your answer to use ` for formatting the code portion of your answer.  That will help with readability.  On the right side of the edit screen, you will see the formatting tips.