# How to register two click events in a row on the same marker

Tags: python, events, plotly-dash

In a Dash app, I would like to toggle the values of a boolean array when markers in a scatterplot are clicked. If I click the same marker twice in a row, I would like to toggle that value twice, but the second click is not registered. I can only click on some *other* marker.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from plotly import graph_objects as go

bools = [False, False, False]

app = Dash(__name__)

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y = [2, 1, 2]))
graph = dcc.Graph(id = 'graph', figure = fig)

app.layout = html.Div(graph)

@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Input('graph', 'clickData')
)
def toggle(clickData):
    global bools
    n_marker = clickData['points'][0]['pointNumber']
    bools[n_marker] = not bools[n_marker]
    print(bools)

app.run_server(debug = True)
```

This seems related to [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412382/clicking-same-plotly-marker-twice-does-not-trigger-events-twice/54755775#54755775) using plotly in R, but I wasn't able to figure out how to use the answers there in python + dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1300#issuecomment-788145161), the solution is to reset the Output in the callback to `None`, as follows:

```
import dash
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash import Dash,Input, Output, html



fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [dash.dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=fig)]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "clickData"),
    Input("graph", "clickData"),
    prevent_initial_call = True
)

def click(clickData):
    x = clickData["points"][0]['x']
    y = clickData["points"][0]['x']
        
    print(f"point is located in x={x} and y={y}")
    
    return None


app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!