# Reset event_data using shinyjs doesn't seem to work anymore, after the recent update

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shinyjs

I am maintaining my code for a big and bulky shiny dashboard, and I noticed that the click-event functionality doesn't reset anymore.

After stripping it down to a minimal working example, and comparing to solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543204/11703379 and https://community.plot.ly/t/reseting-click-events/2718, I come to conclusion that there must have been a change in either `plotly`, or `shinyjs` libraries, which disable this feature.
By halting the execution at the plot, I see that the plot object does carry the source attribute correctly.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),

    plotlyOutput("plot"),

    extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.resetClick = function() { Shiny.onInputChange('.clientValue-plotly_click-plot', 'null'); }"),
    actionButton("reset", "Reset click"),

    verbatimTextOutput("click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$reset, js$resetClick())

    output$click <- renderPrint(event_data("plotly_click", source = "plot"  ))

    output$plot <- renderPlotly(
        plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt,
                  type="scatter",
                  mode="markers",
                  source = "plot") %>%
            event_register("plotly_click")
    )

    output$click <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data(source = "plot","plotly_click")
        if (is.null(d)) "No click" else d
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anyone confirm this?
I am using `plotly` version 4.9.0,
and `shinyjs` version 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like **.clientValue-** is not necessary anymore. Probably a change in `plotly`, but I am not sure about it.

Change `.clientValue-plotly_click-plot` to `plotly_click-plot` and it should work.

#### Output:

[image: Output]